# SQL PHP Set one column to zero if second column doesn't have value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, web, match

I am getting data from Sql using PHP, 2 columns, Amt and Period

usually the amount is clean that means amt and period are both available. Period is 1-12 and the amt is available for these columns

```
Amount  Period 
100 P1
125 P1
150 P2
160 P3
120 P4
130 P5
160 P6
170 P7
180 P8
145 P9
144 P10
155 P11
160 P12
```

I am running a query  to get the amt field and period field from two different tables based on date, etc as shown below

```
SELECT Sum(CONVERT(FLOAT, amt))                  AS sum_amt, 
       CONVERT(FLOAT, Substring(f.period, 2, 4)) AS period 
FROM   bookings b, 
       fiscalcal f 
WHERE  b.[invoice date] >= f.start 
       AND b.[invoice date] <= f.[end] 
       AND f.[year] = '2015' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(FLOAT, Substring(f.period, 2, 4))
```

to get the required data which is correct

I am in a situation, where some periods are missing like P4, P5 is missing, so there is no row with period P4, P5, but on the webpage, I am supposed to display  zero for amount in case of Period P4, P5. I am not able to do this.

so it should look like

```
amount period
225 P1
150 P2
160 P3
 0  P4
 0  P5
160 P6
170 P7
180 P8
145 P9
144 P10
155 P11
165 P12
```

Please help how to do this on PHP and SQL. I would appreciate greatly

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: I am using SQL server, but its using PHP functions, so MYSQL and SQL Server both will work

Comment: Please provide your sql query. It can likely be solved with a CASE

Comment: Why not create a table with all the values you want for Period and then  join the Amt's from Sales? If they come null, then convert them to 0's.

Comment: @ourmandave Actually this is already a million lines table where period is a column being filled when there is amount for that period. In case there is no period there is no row, so I have to display on the webpage zero for that period, as explained in the example above. This table structure cannot be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
    ([Amount] int, [Period] varchar(3));

INSERT INTO YourTable
    ([Amount], [Period])
VALUES
    (100, 'P1'),        (125, 'P1'),
    (150, 'P2'),
    (160, 'P3'),        (120, 'P3'),
    (130, 'P6'),        (160, 'P6'),
    (170, 'P7'),
    (180, 'P8'),
    (145, 'P9'),
    (144, 'P10'),
    (155, 'P11'),
    (160, 'P12');
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66c65/2)**

```
WITH periods (period_id) AS (
    SELECT 'P1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P5' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P6' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P7' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P8' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P9' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P10' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P11' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P12'
)
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(Amount, 0)), p.period_id
FROM periods p
LEFT JOIN YourTable y
       ON p.period_id = y.Period 
GROUP BY p.period_id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|     | period_id |
|-----|-----------|
| 225 |        P1 |
| 150 |        P2 |
| 280 |        P3 |
|   0 |        P4 |
|   0 |        P5 |
| 290 |        P6 |
| 170 |        P7 |
| 180 |        P8 |
| 145 |        P9 |
| 144 |       P10 |
| 155 |       P11 |
| 160 |       P12 |
```

**EDIT**

After your edit looks like you can just put your query inside another cte.

```
WITH periods (period_id) AS (
        SELECT 'P1' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P2' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P3' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P4' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P5' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P6' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P7' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P8' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P9' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P10' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P11' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P12'
    ),
YourTable (Amount, period) AS (
    SELECT Sum(CONVERT(FLOAT, amt))                  AS sum_amt, 
           CONVERT(FLOAT, Substring(f.period, 2, 4)) AS period 
    FROM   bookings b, 
           fiscalcal f 
    WHERE  b.[invoice date] >= f.start 
           AND b.[invoice date] <= f.[end] 
           AND f.[year] = '2015' 
    GROUP  BY CONVERT(FLOAT, Substring(f.period, 2, 4)) 

)
    SELECT SUM(COALESCE(Amount, 0)), p.period_id
    FROM periods p
    LEFT JOIN YourTable y
           ON p.period_id = y.Period 
    GROUP BY p.period_id
```

Comment: Hey @Juan, your code works great, now the thing here is that I am not really getting the data from one table, but I am already doing a join to get Amt and Period from different tables

SELECT      sum(CONVERT(float,Amt)) as sum_amt,  convert(float,substring(f.period,2,4)) as period
FROM         bookings b, fiscalcal f
WHERE     b.[invoice date] >= f.start AND b.[invoice date] <= f.[end] AND f.[year] = '2015'   group by convert(float,substring(f.period,2,4))

I will try to use your code and change my query but if you could help change that would be awesome

Comment: Edit your question. With that information and update the sample data

Comment: Here's what I did. after creating a view of my query, I used your solution, so when I group the data, it is not doing it in sequence, although it is showing 0 for the amt where no period available, but it is not in sequence

`Total_Amt Period3
1193.4 12
2750 5
2750 7
0 11
2750 3
0 4
6450 6
0 8
10236 1
0 2
2750 9
1420 10`

Comment: '
 WITH periods (period_id) AS (
     SELECT '1' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4' UNION ALL
    SELECT '5' UNION ALL
    SELECT '6' UNION ALL
    SELECT '7' UNION ALL
    SELECT '8' UNION ALL
    SELECT '9' UNION ALL
    SELECT '10' UNION ALL
    SELECT '11' UNION ALL
    SELECT '12'
)
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(sum_amt3, 0)) as Total_Amt, p.period_id as Period3
FROM periods p
LEFT JOIN [view_sales for 2015] y
       ON p.period_id = y.Period1 
group BY p.period_id '


it is same for P or without P

Comment: Update the question or update the sqlfiddle I already provide. And you could make a new question. I already answer the question you made and remove my points :(

Comment: cool, even earlier, I was using the view instead of the query, and it was giving me the result but not in sequence. after you made the change, it still gives me the result not in sequence

Comment: well you have to include the `ORDER BY Period` But you will have to change your code from `P1` to `P01` so order works ok. Or include another column`order_id` in the `periods` cte. So are we good now?

Answer (score 0):

Table of valid Periods with a field call Period (including P01 - P12).

```
SELECT periods.period, sum(convert(float,AMT)) as sum_amt2
from Periods
left join Sales on periods.period = substring(sales.period,2,4)
group by periods.period
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, when I used your query, it is not giving me the result in sequence

Comment: @wild_dove21 Just glad you got it working. (I'd forgotten the ORDER BY periods.period.)

Comment: actually I don't think I can use order by as I am doing a sum, so need to group them based on period

Comment: @wild_dove21 I could have sworn you could go an Order By after the Group By.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know I could do that,  it works, but still the sequence is like 1,10,11,12, 2, 3,4... whereas I need 1,2,3,4,...9,10,11,12. Tricky. I even converted to float and all

Comment: @wild_dove21 They didn't even sort as floats? Tricky indeed. =(